# How to rbind in a specific order in r

Tags: r, concatenation, rbind

I have the following separate dataframes :`eGenes`, `all_genes`, `general`, `nsPost`, `nsPre`, `post`, and `pre`. Each of these dataframes have a `Category` column equal to the name of the dataframe, so that when I merge them all together, I know what's what, for instance:

`eGenes`:

```
Gene            pLI             Gene_Symbol     Category
ENSG00000000938 1.771744e-01    FGR             eGenes
ENSG00000000971 9.996310e-01    CFH             eGenes
ENSG00000001036 3.655835e-04    FUCA2           eGenes
```

What I want to do is concatenate them into a single dataframe in a particular order, such that the `Category` column will progress in the order: `eGenes, all_genes, general, pre, post, nsPre, nsPost` (for plotting purposes later).

But when I do `all_lists <- rbind(eGenes, all_genes, general, pre, post, nsPre, nsPost)` and then plot based on `Category`, the plots appear in a different order than that which I expressed in the rbind(). How can I control the order? I even tried concatenating one by one as follows, but that still doesn't work:

```
all_lists_1 <- rbind(eGenes, all_genes, general)
all_lists_2 <- rbind(all_lists_1, pre)
all_lists_3 <- rbind(all_lists_2, post)
all_lists_4 <- rbind(all_lists_3, nsPre)
all_lists <- rbind(all_lists_4, nsPost)
```

**plotting code:**

```
p <- ggplot(all_lists, aes(x=Category, y=pLI, fill=Category)) + geom_violin() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

**UPDATE:**

`unique(all_lists$Category)`:

```
[1] All eGenes               All Genes                General                  Prenatal                 Postnatal                Prenatal (Non-specific)  Postnatal (Non-specific)
Levels: All eGenes All Genes General Postnatal Postnatal (Non-specific) Prenatal Prenatal (Non-specific)
```

`summary(all_lists)`:

```
              Gene            pLI         Gene_Symbol                        Category    
 ENSG00000063978:    6   Min.   :0.000   U1     :   11   All eGenes              : 8206  
 ENSG00000100012:    6   1st Qu.:0.000   Y_RNA  :    7   All Genes               :23790  
 ENSG00000204147:    6   Median :0.025   ASAH2B :    6   General                 : 2887  
 ENSG00000266338:    6   Mean   :0.311   CCDC7  :    6   Postnatal               : 1148  
 ENSG00000000938:    3   3rd Qu.:0.723   HERC2P2:    6   Postnatal (Non-specific):  479  
 ENSG00000000971:    3   Max.   :1.000   MALAT1 :    6   Prenatal                : 1653  
 (Other)        :40172   NA's   :14826   (Other):40160   Prenatal (Non-specific) : 2039
```

Comment: If you need help with the order things appear in a plot, you'll need to share your plotting code. The structure of your data may matter, but how exactly will depend strongly on how you're plotting it.

Comment: You might want to convert column `category` to be a factor with `levels =  c('eGenes', 'all_genes', 'general', 'pre', 'post', 'nsPre', 'nsPost')`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of the `Category` levels by specifying the order of levels, otherwise ggplot will plot according to the alphabetical order.

```
  all_lists$Category <- factor(all_lists$Category, levels = c("eGenes", "all_genes", "general", "pre", "post", "nsPre", "nsPost"))
```

Sample code with `mtcars` dataset

```
library(ggplot2)
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl) # change cyl as factor
mtcars$cyl
 [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
 Levels: 6 8 4
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl, levels = c("6", "8", "4")) # change the order of cyl categories
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg)) + # plot
  geom_violin()
```

[image]

Comment: When I run that, it just turns all the values in the `Category` column to `NA`.

Comment: Could you check if Category is a factor?

Comment: How do I check that? I tried running `all_lists$Category <- factor(all_lists$Category)` and then `all_lists$Category <- factor(all_lists$Category, levels = c("eGenes", "all_genes", "general", "pre", "post", "nsPre", "nsPost"))`, but the Category column is still all `NA`.

Comment: What is the results of th following commands: 1) all_lists$Category 2) summary(all_lists)